# How do I directly create and output a .gz file with PHP

Tags: php

I'm making a dynamic sitemap and i want it gziped before output. How do I do that? What header should I add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [this page](http://www.webcodingtech.com/php/gzip-compression.php) two methods for sending gzipped output are outlined.

The easiest solution is to use output buffering with the ob_gzhandler:

```
<?php
    ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
?>
```

The ob_gzhandler will take care of setting the correct headers. It also does not gzip the data in case the client does not support gzip encoding.

However, the ob_gzhandler requires that the Zlib library is enabled. For more details see the documentation of [ob_gzhandler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php).